# adding a new subpanel to an existing panel

Tags: scripting, texture-painting

Blender's modes have their own panels:
[image]

Basically in this case, I'd like to add a subpanel, with some properties, to the already existing `Stroke` panel in the texture paint mode. How do I do this?

Comment: How much python have you worked with before? If you right click the ui element, do you see a pop up that includes 'edit source'. If you click that, you can switch to the Scripting layout and choose the 'space_view3d_toolbar.py' and then see a highlighted line where the element is located. Script is there that you can experiment with to add what you want there, or you can go about creating an add-on yourself to do what you want since the interface is all in python.

Comment: @CraigDJones , I have python experience but only with django, bpy is sort of confusing with me, but doc is not as detailed as django's :) . But, I want to know without editing the space_view3d_toolbar.py , is it possible to create the subpanel inside the shown panel? Like getting a reference to the created panel and inserting a subpanel on top of it.

Comment: I'd start slow with one of the packaged templates and experiment with getting additional buttons to show up in the panel of your choice, consistently and then attach the operators/settings you want there. The existing add-ons you use can give you a lot of clues here. After, you can package as an add-on so that you can share it or at lt consistently keep it in place on your machines.

Comment: @CraigDJones, I just made a Rig script that has sliders for IK/FK switches and toggling bone layers, and so have a basic understanding of adding buttons into panels, I do know to add a new slot of panel in the texture paint mode, but I want to know _if it is possible_ to add a panel to an already existing panel(in the above slot in our example), without changing the `space_view3d_toolbar.py` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `bl_parent_id` in the panel.

If this is set, the panel becomes a sub-panel.